# Javascript XML Parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

We've sets of webservices and we have to make request on clientside (sending request to getting response in a jason format, and parsing XML document through - having XSLT support would be great).

We need a Javascript library which will be independently responsible to all the above work and should handle browser compatibility issues.

I did some googling and at this moment [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery?oldid=20032) looks as an appropriate option to catch

Please, suggest if this would be a fair choice or am I missing anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/) library out. It brings many pseudo-standard (implemented in every browser but IE) XML APIs to Internet Explorer, such as DOMParser, XMLSerializer, XSLTProcessor.

Comment: The problem is IE is a priority :)

Comment: So use the recommended library - it normalizes APIs across all browsers. Even if you only target IE, using that API is better than working directly with ActiveX-based objects.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely going to read about it in detail. Actually, I need something which is compatible to all browsers and if there is no such solution for it then I will put IE in a priority. As you said it will work with IE then there is no issue to give it a try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Sergey, I am also considering jquery for XML parsing. Could you please suggest will that be a good choice to go with. Here what I am considering: http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery?oldid=20032

Comment: Ramiz, I guess you are considering using jQuery not for XML parsing but for DOM traversing. If so, I am not sure if jQuery works properly with XMLDOM (that is different in IE from HTMLDOM, for example). Try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know one a XML parser that is provided by openjs.

Please do [visit](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/xml_parser/) the site

There is one library provided by [JASON](http://json.org/). You can find more details [here](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/)

Comment: I doubt Ramiz was asking for a true XML parser - why would someone need one? All browsers support XML DOM natively