# Is there any easy to use Javascript XML library recommend?

Tags: javascript, xml

I parse data using JSON in javascript, I find this is very convenient. But when I using XML, I need to look down every nodes. It seems that the XML is more complex. Is there any Javascript for erase some plain on creating and reading xml document? plx recommend.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124654/javascript-xml-parser

Comment: and stackoverflow.com/questions/1031231/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [JKL ParseXML](http://www.kawa.net/works/js/jkl/parsexml-e.html) It's a lightweight single-purpose library and works very well.

Answer (score 2):

[Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/) is an ECMAScript library acting as a cross-browser wrapper for native XML APIs. It offers various XML related goodies like Document instantiation, XML loading from URLs or strings, XSLT transformations, XPath queries etc and comes especially handy for people doing what is lately known as "AJAX" development.

Answer (score -1):

How about [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)? I feel very comfortable manipulating and processing both html and xml data. Take a look at the following to give a hint on how it will be processing xml using jquery.

- http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-makes-parsing-xml-easy
- http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/
- http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery?oldid=20032

In case you want to know, jQuery is good at easing your life with JSON too, you may take a look at the [`getJSON`](http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson) function to know more about it.

Comment: jQuery is meant to be HTML (case-insensitive) and XML is case-sensitive. Manipulating your XML using jQuery library will certainly make your XML lowercase, and possibly causing errors in your app.

Comment: That... is a good point. Never realized it :)

Answer (score -1):

I have to throw in a plug for MooTools. Like jQuery, it greatly simplifies working with the DOM, and offers a great, very simple AJAX and JSON API as well.

http://mootools.net/